# PHP Wordpress loop causing cards to render inside cards instead of separately

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a simple loop on a wordpress homepage that pulls in 3 random articles. It's intermittently rendering the cards inside the other cards instead of 3 separate cards. I feel like it's a timing issue being caused from pulling them in randomly. Is there a way to force them to render separately?

```
<div class="row">
    <?php 
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'orderby'   => 'rand',
            'posts_per_page' => '3'
        );

        $loop = new WP_Query($args); ?>
        
    <?php if ( $loop->have_posts() ) : ?>
        <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
            <div class="card" data-url="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail('homepage-thumbs', array( 'class' => 'aligncenter' )); ?>
                    <h3><a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                    <span><i class="fal fa-user"></i> by <?php the_author(); ?></span>
                    <p></p>
                    <p><?php echo substr(get_the_content(), 0, 128); ?>...</p>  
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Try to make `$loop` global before using. `global $loop; $loop = new WP_Query($args);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add wp_reset_postdata after your loop, like

```
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code works in my test.  However, I would use the `wp_trim_words` to create your excerpt rather than what you did, which could cut a word in the middle.

```
<div class="row">
    <?php 
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'orderby'   => 'rand',
            'posts_per_page' => '3'
        );

        $loop = new WP_Query($args); ?>
        
    <?php if ( $loop->have_posts() ) : ?>
        <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
            <div class="card" data-url="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail('homepage-thumbs', array( 'class' => 'aligncenter' )); ?>
                    <h3><a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                    <span><i class="fal fa-user"></i> by <?php the_author(); ?></span>
                    <p></p>
                    <p><?php 
                        $theContent = get_the_content();
                        // strip out any shortcodes from the excerpt
                        $theContent = strip_shortcodes( $theContent );
                        // wp_trim_words($content, number_of_words, read_more_text)
                        echo wp_trim_words( $theContent, 30 , '...' );?></p>  
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Good catch.Thanks!